# Run a unix shell script present on another server from a differnt server

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have server 1 where shell script1 is placed. I want to execute shell script 2 present on another server from the shell script1 itself which is on server 1.
This is what I am trying to do.

```
ftp -nv $hostname << END
 quote user $UID
 quote pass $pwd
 binary
 put $source_file
quit
 END
 rc=$?
 echo "Return Code:$rc"
 if [ $rc == 0 ]
 then
 **execute My_port script (present on remote server) which works on the ftpd file and do something**.
 else
 exit 1
 fi
```

hope I make the requirement clear.

Does anyone have any idea on that?

Comment: You're going to need to look at ssh to achieve that - key exchange between the servers and then ssh user@host 'command to run'

Comment: @FreudianSlip so if I have ssh access on the remote server and I want to run a script say my_port.sh, what code should I write in the then part of my code

Comment: @user3901666: my answer gives it

Comment: ssh user@host  sh my_port.sh .. that's all?

Comment: Thanks a lot @FreudianSlip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run any program remotely, you need (on the remote machine) some [server program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_(computing)) capable of that (and on the local machine, some client program compatible with it).

Usually, you'll use [ssh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) (read its `man` page [ssh(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html)). Perhaps you'll have some [openssh](https://www.openssh.com/) server. You'll find many SSH [tutorials](http://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Linux) on the web (you probably want to use a [public key](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/public-key-authentication) to avoid needing to type a password).

There is also [rsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Shell), but without encryption so insecure. You probably don't want it, and it would be foolish to use it on anything else than a trusted local network.

So your shell script could contain something like `ssh remotehost My_port script arguments`...

Be also aware of the [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (it is different on the local machine and on the remote ones, in general). It does matter, notably its remote settings, for commands (and remote commands). You might need to give the full path of scripts (e.g. `ssh remotehost /home/remoteuser/bin/myport.sh` ...) If the *remote* `PATH` setting don't have the directory containing the script. You could use `ssh remotehost 'echo $PATH'` to query the remote `PATH` setting.

Comment: so if I have ssh access on the remote server and I want to run a script say my_port.sh, what code should I write in the then part of my code

Comment: As written in my answer, it could be `ssh remotehost my_port.sh arguments`